# Proper usage of $wpdb->update()?

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I am trying to update my custom table in Wordpress using the following php code but still no success:

```
$tablename = "wpfeedback";
$data = array(
        'mark' => $mark, 
        'comment' => $feedback_comment
        );
$format= array('%s','%s');
$where = array( 'main_id' => $main_id );
$wpdb->update($tablename, $data, $where, $format);
```

When trying to update the data:

> positive -> negative AND
>   Test 1: New post -> Test 2: Edit post

After `var_dump( $wpdb->last_query )`, the result:

```
string(98) "UPDATE `wpfeedback` SET `mark` = 'positive', `comment` = 'Test 1: New post' WHERE `main_id` = '34'"
```

The above usage of `$wpdb`. The problem I had was I put wrong vars on the input and textarea that's why it seems not updating. Good thing I used `var_dump()`. Thank you for the help @Milo!

Comment: have you looked at the [example in codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows)?

Comment: I read the examples above and I came up with this line `$wpdb->update($tablename, $data, array( 'main_id' => $main_id, $format ));` but when trying it there's an error: `Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string`. my `$format` is wrong?

Comment: @Milo I updated my question according to what I read in the link you gave, still didn't updated. Anything I miss?